# Express 4.x closes connections after 2 minutes

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple node application which handles `GET /foo`. This request takes some time to compute and return a file. 
Each time the request lasts more than 2 minutes, the connection is closed. I'm using Express 4.10.2 and node 0.10.32.

I read that http module has a default timeout of 2 minutes: http://contourline.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/preventing-server-timeout-in-node-js/

I tried to use:

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(5*60*1000); //5 minutes
});
```

But even if the connection is not closed after two minutes, when the server tried to send the file back, I got:

`{ [Error: Request aborted] code: 'ECONNABORT' }`

EDIT:

`server.setTimeout(5*60*1000);` works fine! Thanks @mscdex

Comment: Did you try `server.setTimeout(5*60*1000)` outside of the `connection` event handler?

Comment: I'll try that. let you know in a few. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`server.setTimeout()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) is the method that sets the HTTP connection timeout for all connections.